# npm install forked git with submodule

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I'm trying to get npm to install `node-gitteh` as a dependency via `npm install` which reads from `package.json`.  Unfortunately this npm package is broken in node 0.6.x, but no problem as there's a forked repo that fixes the issues (https://github.com/hughsk/node-gitteh.git).

Now the issue is that this forked repo has a submodule, so if I try to download the tar from github in the `package.json`:

```
, "dependencies" : {
    "gitteh" : "https://github.com/hughsk/node-gitteh/tarball/master"
}
```

I get an error that equates to "submodule folder not found". If I clone the same repo manually and do a recursive submodule update and an `npm install` from the `node-gitteh` folder, it works fine, but I can't figure out how to get npm to do this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've had the same problem and so far have just relied on cloning my module into node_modules and doing a submodule update manually. It would be nice to have npm handle this automatically.

In package.json there's a scripts field (see [npm docs](http://npmjs.org/doc/json.html))
So could do

```
"scripts":{"preinstall": "git submodule update -i -r"}
```

See https://github.com/isaacs/octave-test for an example of this.

Comment: npm doesn't copy `.gitmodules`, so that will only work locally :(

Comment: In my case npm happens to give me a .gitmodules, but that's still not enough without the .git files to tell me what version to install. :(

Comment: Mine keeps the `.gitmodules` file, but that's it. None of the other git metadata comes down and the submodule directories just don't show up at all.

Answer (score -2):

According to [the docs](https://npmjs.org/doc/json.html#Git-URLs-as-Dependencies), you need to supply the git url in a special format.
Also, it needs to point to git repo (same address you would use for `git clone`), not the tarball provided by github.

In your case (git over https), it would be:

```
, "dependencies" : {
  "gitteh" : "git+https://github.com/hughsk/node-gitteh"
}
```

Using this, npm will default to the master branch.